# What's the best and easy way to build a cloud based SaaS product?

Tags: web, web-applications, cloud, saas

am working on a project and don't have experience with developing applications, I want like the BEST and EASY way to build cloud based SaaS product.

Can anyone tell which tech stack I should use, which backend lang/framework, db, which cloud company etc? I know only php in backend as of now but am thinking to first learn js and then nodeJS and then use it for backend and for db am thinking to use mysql.

There's something which might affect your answer, am actually not expecting much traffic on it not even in future. Please tell considering both the scenarios, application with very low traffic expectation and application with high traffic.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the best way is to sit down and write out exactly what product you want to build - what's it's audience, it's purpose, what are your requirements around security, availability, etc, what kind of information is it going to process, how is this information gathered and retrieved - and then look at what skills you have access to, or could acquire easily. That will determine what technology stack would work for you. I'm sure folks on Slack will be happy to help with that once it's clearer what you're trying to achieve.

If you don't want to put details of your product design on Stack, get advice from someone offline.

In terms of cloud hosting, for a small-scale project they're probably all going to be just fine, but the technology stack you choose would help determine which might work best.